Help on deoxidize yellow on white shoe sole
I'm trying to remove yellow stain on my white shoe sole, i tried with hydrogen peroxide 3% but it doesn't work maybe because its too weak, should i try with 50%? or i need to dilute it to lower percentage. because I'm afraid it will ruin my shoe, it was a gift from my mentor so it's a valuable shoes for me, or maybe do you guys have other alternatives to unyellow white shoes

A photo would be helpful.

do you know anything about the nature of the stain?


One does not deoxidize with H2O2. 2. What is the stain? Some might be made worse, or better, or totally unaffected by H2O2.


H2O2 acts as an oxidizer not a deoxidizer
